# Use ObjPtr(Me) to return the Name of a Custom Class Instance?

Tags: excel, vba

I understand that [ObjPtr](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199824) will return the address of an object in memory and that it points to a structure called IUNKNOWN and that there is some kind of Interface definition encoded in that to expose the Object structure, but I couldn't figure out how to determine the interfaces for a VBA Custom Class Object and how to use that to return the Name property of an Object.

It's more "nice to have" than essential, but I just want to know the name of an object instance at run time so that I can include it in my trace messages.

Can anyone explain how to do this or, better yet direct me to a reference so I can figure it out?

**EDIT**

To re-state my aim:

To make a custom class objects that is able to figure out the name of its particular instance.

For example

```
Dim oObject1 as Class1, oObject2 as Class1
Set oObject1 = New Class1
Set oObject2 = New Class1
Debug.Print oObject1.instanceName & " " & oObject2.instanceName
```

In the immediate window:

```
oObject1 oObject2
```

Is this possible in VBA?

If VBA runtime has a [Symbol Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) - since it is interpretive I think maybe it does - and I had a way of exposing it, then I could make a Property Get procedure to access the symbol Table and search on the Address - ObjPtr(Me) - to return the semantic name of the instance of the class.

I'm pretty sure this is a dumb question but, hopefully, the process of realising its a dumb question is helpful to my understanding.

**Example of a Symbol Table**

```
Address Type    Name
00000020    a   T_BIT
00000040    a   F_BIT
00000080    a   I_BIT
20000004    t   irqvec
20000008    t   fiqvec
2000000c    t   InitReset
20000018    T   _main
20000024    t   End
```

Comment: but what is `ObjPtr` which you mentioned? you should provide any code, any web link, whatever...!?

Comment: Already checked [this](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/varptr.asp) one?

Comment: @BK201 Yes, I had that one thanks... but it only talks about the address returned for an object, no description of how to figure out the interface to access the properties of the object or the name of it.

Comment: `the name of an object instance at runtime` - isn't a *name* any longer. You have named your object to be able to work with it and reference in your code. While the code gets compiled the name is gone and the runtime doesn't refer to the object by it's name. You would need to use some sort of [**reflection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) to get the actual name or build a debugged that would store the name and reference at run-time. I am not sure I understand your question - can you elaborate a bit more on the connection you see between the ObjPtr and name?

Comment: @mehow Ah, Ok. I get it now. Its not stored with the object... It would only be in the runtime symbol table. Sorry, Im a bit rusty. Then I guess that's what I want. I want to get the address of an object using ObjPtr and use that to look up the associated name of the variable in the runtime symbol table. Can?

Comment: @CoolBlue there is no name at runtime in vba. It doesn't exist so you can't retrieve it...

Comment: @mehow yep. I figured. Thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: @mehow thanks for the link about Reflections, I just had a chance to read it. No, its not like that, its much more basic. It's just a Symbol Table that I thought might exist because VBA is interpretive. Compilers have Symbol Tables and I was figuring that for an interpretive language, the Symbol Table must exist at run time. I'm still researching this so I will post a response later in case any body else has a similar misunderstanding.

Comment: @CoolBlue Sorry maybe I misunderstood something here, are you after the Locals Window or Watch Window? That is your Symbol Table in VBA

Comment: @mehow By symbol table I mean, for example http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/~tshsu/compiler2006/slides/slide5. I'm talking about the cross reference between semantic symbol names and physical memory address. And my nieve idea is to access it programmatically. All compilers and cross assemblers have these.

Comment: @CoolBlue sorry but I can't access that link, update your question with a screenshot maybe?

Comment: @CoolBlue I now do understand your question and it was very simple from the beginning - "can I access the name of an instance of a class at runtime?". I feel that I already answered your question though - I don't know if there is anything else to say :)

Comment: @mehow Yes. Exactly. And I guess the answer is "No" thanks for your guidance :)

Comment: hm... maybe you can but I need to give this a good thought (*as of now I dont think that's possible in VBA*). Why not create a property for the class to store the name of each instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `NO` for an answer. It's not possible to return an instance name *as a String* literal  in VBA.

I still don't understand the reason you may want to do that... Anyway

The easiest way to know each instance *code name* would be to create a property for a class that stores the actual name. This would only expose the name as a String property and not an actual reference to the object - it already has a reference - itself!

So create a class module

**Class1**

```
Option Explicit

Public MyName as String
```

and in **Module1** all it takes is

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Dim c As Class1
    Set c = New Class1

    c.MyName = "c"

    Debug.Print c.MyName

End Sub
```

And there you go :)

---

Another way would be to create a Dictionary to store both KEY/VALUE pairs.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim c As Class1
    Set c = New Class1

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    dict.Add "c", c

    Debug.Print dict.Exists("c")

End Sub
```

---

Now, it's possible to actually do what you want but it would be a really ugly way. Here's how as I am not going to demonstrate.

You would create an instance of a custom class. Using ObjPtr you can get it's reference in memory. Then you would need a mechanism that scans your module code line by line and finds names of all variables you've dimensioned. Once you retrieve a list of all variables you would need a mechanism which *tries* to create an instance of the same type (class). Once you get past that point you could try to `myNewObj = c` (*"c" would be the obj instance*) programmatically. If that succeed then you would do ObjPt for both and match their addresses in memory - you get a match you know the variable name. Grree please do not do it that way :P

Comment: yes, I also thought of the Name property solution... And the process you describe (and no, don't worry, I won't go there...) is the exact opposite of what the compiler does to generate and manage the SYMBOL TABLE.  If I could access that it would be easy.   Oh, and +1 for the most ingenious work-around in the history of programming ...

Comment: Thanks @CoolBlue. I don't think anyone's tried this yet I may have a go one of these days haha

Answer (score 1):

`TypeName(obj)` will return the Type of any variable in VBA:

```
Dim c as Class1
set c = new Class1 
Debug.print TypeName(c) '==> "Class1"
```

FYI, I've also historically wanted to access the symbol table also. The idea was to get local variables from the previous scope by name. In that way you could make string interpolation:

```
a = "World"
Debug.Print StringInterp("Hello ${a}")
```

https://github.com/sancarn/VBA-STD-Library/blob/master/docs/VBAMemoryAnalysis.txt
https://github.com/sancarn/VBA-STD-Library/blob/master/docs/VBAMemoryAnalysis2.txt

No luck making a general function yet.