# Print a variable's name

Tags: excel, vba

I might be bad at googling as I couldn't find the answer to below question:

```
Sub TEST()
Dim sthstring as string
sthstring = "Hello World"
end sub
```

While we all know it's easy to use msgbox to print **"Hello world"**, is it possible to print out the variable's name (which in this case, **"sthstring"**) and how?

EDIT: please do not provide with answer such as:

```
Dim someotherstring as string  
someotherstring = "sthstring"
```

as I meant to find a way to print the 'name' of the variable, thanks

Comment: If you already know the variable called `sthstring`, why do you need another way to find out its name? The name is right there.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the question.  I know it might not make sense and there are alternatives, but I would like to found out if printing the variable's name itself is doable.

Comment: There must be more to your question, I think you have simplified your situation too far. Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do?

Comment: If you're looking to debug your code, you could just use the Locals Window, which has the names of variables in scope and their current values.

Comment: It is something similar to a code challenge that I am working on - to print out the exact code that used to print out the code... if that make sense to you all.  Hence I am looking if that's possible, thanks

Comment: Oh, you mean like a [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing))? There might be another way to do what you're looking for - quines in most languages don't need to find out names of their own variables.

Comment: Quine looks like what I am after!  Thanks all, I will check out more on quine and/or string-based value lookup, hopefully come back with an answer to my question.

Comment: These services are more likely exposed by the implementing host application, E.g. Excel; `x = Workbooks(1).VBProject.VBComponents(5).CodeModule.Lines(3, 1)`

Comment: To  my mind, this is only a meaningful question if your talking about a particular instance of a Custom Class. For example an instanceName property. This would be useful to me, mainly for debugging purposes. To do this you need the base address of the object and access to the runtime symbol table.  If your thinking about self modifying code then... Step away from the keyboard... (No down-vote from me by the way)

Comment: @CoolBlue no worries on the downvote thing; mainly I am concern about making a good question which is benefit to my job anyways.  Also sounds to me like self-modifying code is some kind of forbidden magic hah... thanks by the way!

Comment: No, I think it's a good question :) In fact, I asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487567/use-objptrme-to-return-the-name-of-a-custom-class-instance I worked with a guy one time who used to love to write the meanest, dirtiest, bit-bashing assembler code you ever saw. Self modifying was one if his favourite tricks until he had to burn it to EPROM. Hmm, guess I'm showing my age there!

Comment: I guess either he loves showoff or he just hate every other programmers =D.

Comment: Nope, he was just eccentric... and very, very *creative*. Such people have their uses, but you need to use them wisely ;)

Comment: That sounds just like my manager :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading comments I think you may find this answer useful.

VBA doesn't support reflection just like @Monty Wild has mentioned already but adding references to *`Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3`* grants you the access the VBE object. You can then iterate object modules in your VBA Project and retrieve the entire code for a module in a `String` format.

Consider the following (*Stick it in a new workbook's `Module1`*)

```
Sub Main()

    Dim code As String
    code = GetCodeModule("Module1")

    Debug.Print code

End Sub

Private Function GetCodeModule(ByVal codeModuleName As String) As String
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

    Set VBProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(codeModuleName)
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    GetCodeModule = CodeMod.Lines(1, CodeMod.CountOfLines)
End Function
```

Your `code` variable now stores the exact code that is in your `Module1` you can check that by opening the Immediate Window <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.

You may want to write/use some sort of a `Find` function to disassemble the String components to retrieve variable names and values but I wouldn't recommend doing it as it's can get quite tricky.

Comment: it looks like I can make use of this to actually "modify" my existing code, like adding / subtracting lines in the editor.  this is getting more fun.  Thanks by the way

Comment: @Alex now all this is it's a string storing the code, if you want to modify code (not recommended though) you need a variable and reference to a `CodeMode` variable

Comment: now thanks!  I will definitly play safe before fully understand what it is.

Answer (score 5):

You can go a step further that simply accessing the code.

Updating the excellent code from [Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) to

- show that setting the reference to *Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3* isnt a pre-requisite to access the VBIDE
- actually parse out any `Dim XX As String` in any codemodule and report it

*sample output*

> Dim sthstring As String (Module1 at: Line: 2)
>   Dim strSub As String (Module2 at: Line: 2)
>   Dim FindWhat As String (Module2 at: Line: 11)
>   Dim ProcName As String (Module3 at: Line: 9)

*code*

```
 Sub GetVariable()
 Dim strSub As String
 strSub = "As String"
 Call SearchCodeModule(strSub)
 End Sub
```

> ```
>  Function SearchCodeModule(ByVal strSub)
>         Dim VBProj As Object
>         Dim VBComp As Object
>         Dim CodeMod As Object
>         Dim FindWhat As String
>         Dim SL As Long ' start line
>         Dim EL As Long ' end line
>         Dim SC As Long ' start column
>         Dim EC As Long ' end column
>         Dim Found As Boolean
> ```

```
        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
        Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

        With CodeMod
            SL = 1
            EL = .CountOfLines
            SC = 1
            EC = 255
            Found = .Find(target:=strSub, StartLine:=SL, StartColumn:=SC, _
                EndLine:=EL, EndColumn:=EC, _
                wholeword:=False, MatchCase:=False, patternsearch:=False)
            Do Until Found = False
                If Left$(Trim(.Lines(SL, 1)), 3) = "Dim" Then Debug.Print Trim(.Lines(SL, 1) & " (" & CStr(VBComp.Name) & " at: Line: " & CStr(SL)) & ")"
                EL = .CountOfLines
                SC = EC + 1
                EC = 255
                Found = .Find(target:=strSub, StartLine:=SL, StartColumn:=SC, _
                    EndLine:=EL, EndColumn:=EC, _
                    wholeword:=True, MatchCase:=False, patternsearch:=False)
            Loop
        End With
        Next VBComp
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks!  It's good to know MS for Applications Extensibility 5.3 isn't the only way out.  However I do want to clarify the use of "column" in the code - is the VB editor actually divided into rows and columns just as the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 3):

This is difficult to do directly, as VBA does not have reflection, i.e. cannot directly reference itself.

However;

Since in a comment you mention that you want to write code that references itself, you can do so by referencing `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3` in the tools/references dialog.  This gives you the ability to reference VBA code, and from there you could write code that prints itself out.

See

- [MSFT reference 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa189282%28v=office.10%29.aspx), and
- [MSFT reference 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443985%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Monty, I will take some time look into VBA Extensibility 5.3, that might be just what I need, similar to Quine.

Comment: +1 for suggesting this first. Although you dont actually need to set the reference to access the VBIDE.

Answer (score 1):

That is likely impossible, as variable names are just pointers to data. You can have several variables that all point to the same object (although in VBA I do not believe strings are treated as objects so that would not be possible, with the exception of a ByRef function call).

Comment: Thanks Aaron for the explanation