# VBA: Get name of variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables

is there a function or a property to get a variables name?

Something like

`msgBox myVariable.name`
or

`msgBox nameOfVariable(myVariable)`

that returns `"myVariable"` when I defined it with e.g. `myVariable = "whatever"`?
Google just brings questions to variable referencing...

Comment: why would you want to do that? XY problem?

Comment: I want some variables to be filled into cells specified by the names (of variables and cells).

Comment: no there isn't. you must use either a `Dictionary` object or a `Class`

Comment: `myVariable` is the name of the variable `myVariable`. To assign it to a cell, simply do `[A1] = myVariable`

Comment: @alve89 could you rephrase this : "_I want some variables to be filled into cells specified by the names (of variables and cells)._" ? I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Old thread, I know, but see and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173082/print-a-variables-name for a possible approach.

Answer (score 2):

a possible Class approach would be the following (commented):

1. Add Class Module

   in VBA IDE

   - click Insert-> Class Module
   - click View -> Property Window
   - enter `(Name)` property textbox and type in "Variable" (or whatever you may prefer but be consistent with in following steps)
   - enter the following code in the `Class` code pane

     ```
     Option Explicit

     'declare the fields that will be attached to every instance of this class
     Public name As String '<--| this will store the name of the variable to which you'll set the object of this class
     Public value As Variant '<--| this will store the value associated with the variable to which you'll set the object of this class

     'declare a `method` to write the `value` of the object in the named range named after the `name` field 
     Sub WriteRange(Optional wb As Variant) '<--| you can pass the reference of the workbook whose named ranges you want to exploit
        If IsMissing(wb) Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook '<--| if no workbook reference is passed then the currently active workbook is assumed
        If TypeName(wb) = "Workbook" Then '<-- check for a proper workbook reference being passed)
             On Error Resume Next '<-- to prevent unassigned named range throw an error
             wb.Names(name).RefersToRange.value = value '<--| write the  value of the `value` filed of the current instance in the named range of the passed workbook named after the `name` filed of the current instance
         End If
     End Sub
     ```
2. Exploit `Variable` Class in your code

   as an example of exploiting the `Variable` class for three variables with, say, a `String` value for the 1st, an `Integer` value for the 2nd and a `Double` value for the 3rd, in any module code pane enter the following code:

   ```
       Option Explicit

       Sub main()
           Dim myVariable1 As Variable, myVariable2 As Variable, myVariable3 As Variable '<--| declare your variables of type "Variable": choose whatever name you may want

           Set myVariable1 = CreateVariable("myVariable1", "this is a string value") '<-- set your 1st variable with its name (you must use the same name as the variable!) and value (myVariable1 will have a `String`type value)
           Set myVariable2 = CreateVariable("myVariable2", 10) '<-- set your 2nd variable with its name (you must use the same name as the variable!) and value (myVariable2 will have a `Integer`type value)
           Set myVariable3 = CreateVariable("myVariable3", 0.3)'<-- set your 3rd variable with its name (you must use the same name as the variable!) and value (myVariable3 will have a `Double` type value)

           'exploit `WriteRange` method of your Class to write the object value into the corresponding named range: you must have set proper named ranges in your currently active workbook
           myVariable1.WriteRange '<--| this will write the string "this is a string value" in named range "myVariable1" of your currently active workbook
           myVariable2.WriteRange '<--| this will write the number '10' in named range "myVariable2" of your currently active workbook
           myVariable3.WriteRange '<--| this will write the number '0.3' in named range "myVariable3" of your currently active workbook 
       End Sub

       ' helper Function to create an object of `Variable` class and initialize its `name` and `value` properties 
       Function CreateVariable(name As String, value As Variant) As Variable '<--| the function returns an object of `Variable` class
           Set CreateVariable = New Variable '<--| this creates a new object of `Variable` class
           With CreateVariable '<--| refer to the newly created object and ...
               .name = name '<--| ... set its `name` property ...
               .value = value '<--| ... and its `value` property
           End With
       End Function
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few variables then a class module is over kill.
While it is true that a class module is a template that can be copied, I have explored a simplification which mimics a class module.

Create a standard module with the name of your variable as the module name.
Inside this module create functions like `Name`, `Value`
e.g.

```
Function Name()
    Name = "myNewName"
End Function

Function Value()
    Value = 10
End Function
```

in a cell, paste `=my_VBA_Project.myVariable.Name()`

The drawback is that the values are hard coded like a constant. To change the values, you need to edit the function values manually.

I use this format in my VBA programming to simulate OOP.