# Multiple dictionaries for each unique key (VBA)

Tags: vba, dictionary

Is it possible to have multiple dictionaries that automatically add keys ending with the same number into it?

What i have in mind is something like this:

```
dicInfo (i). add (key (i), value)
```

so when there are keys like key1, key2, key3, they are added to dicInfo1, dicInfo2 etc?

Thanks!

Comment: I mean aKey1, bKey1 that goes into dicInfo1 as keys. these are string keys yes, so it's a value

Comment: Key1 is the variable name.

Comment: Maybe something along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116580/vba-get-name-of-variable

Comment: @Lucky0683 -  Here is an excellent [**Guide to the Excel VBA Dictionary**](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#Checking_if_a_Key_Exists), including examples of how to do all the standard stuff and more. Also, here's an equally excellent ["Ultimate Guide To Collections in Excel VBA](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/), from the same dude.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to add Dictionaries to a Dictionary and return the values

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim dic As Object, key As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For j = 1 To 100
        key = CLng(Right(j, 1))
        If Not dic.Exists(key) Then dic.Add key:=key, Item:=CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dic(key).Add dic(key).Count, j
    Next

    For j = 0 To 9
        Debug.Print Join(dic(j).Keys(), ",")
        Debug.Print Join(dic(j).Items(), ",")
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you!  But this seems to be just having keys as 1,2,3..? Does it add 1,2,3 behind each key? i want the key to be akey1, bkey2, ckey3

Comment: The keys can be anything