# VBA Dictionary References

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, reference

I am not a professional programmer, but reasonably proficient in VBA. I currently am writing a program to analyze a large database. When I find the area in the database that needs further analysis and potential correction, my desired approach is to collect the necessary data in a number of dictionaries with a common structure.

While I can declare the dictionaries with early binding, I need a way to reference each dictionary with a variable name I can then use to create a loop to quickly analyze all the information I collected. Ideally, I would want to name the dictionaries something like A1, A2, A3, etc. and then just create a loop where I increment through the numerical part of the name as all the data in each dictionary is analyzed/corrected in the same manner.

While I know indirect references cannot be used in standard VBA, it is possible to use Object Variables for each of the dictionaries. However, Object Variables themselves to not appear to have the flexibility to have a variable structure. This appears possible with some objects like WorkSheets, where the variable name can be defined in parentheses behind WorkSheets (i.e. WorkSheets("A1")), but does not appear possible for dictionaries, collections, arraylists, or any other type of storage mechanism I might use.

I can do what I want to do by creating nested dictionaries and some cobbled up names for the keys. I have some data which would require a different dictionary item for the same key value. Thus I need to create different "versions" of the same key. Needless to say, while this approach can work, the analysis would be much simpler if I could just loop through the names.

Hopefully, I described my problem adequately. Am I totally out of luck in what I am trying to do or does someone have an idea on how to achieve this? Thanks much!

Comment: In a dictionary of dictionaries, each key's item is a second tier dictionary. The item for each key in the top tier can easily be created and later retrieved with a unique concatenated string as the key and a dictionary object as the item. What am I missing?

Comment: I agree with Jeeped. What you want (seemingly) is an associative array, and the Dictionary is an implementation of that in the VB languages. As a side note, the Worksheets object has a default property `.Item` which accepts both string and integer as an index, `Worksheets("Name")` is a shorthand for `Worksheets.Item("Name")`. (The Dictionary is probably better than that for your case.)

Comment: This has come up a number of times even just recently.I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261099/multiple-dictionaries-for-each-unique-key-vba/51261519#51261519) was the most recent re-occurence.

Answer (score 7):

I, too, had plenty of years experience with VBA before I finally figured out **VBA Dictionaries** (and **Collections**).  I'm not fully clear on your question, and therefore this may not directly solve your problem, but I've been looking for an excuse to pass along an excellent resource I discovered (and I frequently refer to) on both topics:

- Paul Kelley : [**Excel VBA Dictionary – A Complete Guide**](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)
- Paul Kelley : [**The Ultimate Guide To Collections in Excel VBA**](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/)

---

Just so I'm not posting a link-only answer, here's an excerpt:

## VBA Dictionaries common tasks cheat sheet:

### [Early Binding](https://msofficefun.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/early-binding-vs-late-binding-in-office-vba/)

> **Library/Reference *(early binding)***
> *`Microsoft Scripting Runtime`*
>    *(Add using `Tools`->`References` from the VBE)*
>
> **Declare *(early binding)***
>      `Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary`
>
> **Create *(early binding)***
>      `Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary`

---

### [Late Binding](http://excelmatters.com/2013/09/23/vba-references-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/)

> **Declare *(late binding)***
>      `Dim dict As Object`
>
> **Create(late binding)**
>      `Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`

---

### Add/Change/Get

> **Add item (key must not already exist)**
>      `dict.Add Key, Value`
> <sub><sup>e.g.</sup></sub> `dict.Add "Apples", 50`
>
> **Change value at key. Automatically adds if the key does not exist.**
>     `dict(Key) = Value`
> <sub><sup>e.g.</sup></sub> `dict("Oranges") = 60`
>
> **Check if key exists**
>     `dict.Exists(Key)`
> <sub><sup>e.g.</sup></sub> `If dict.Exists("Apples") Then`
>
> **Get the number of items**
>     `dict.Count`
>
> **Get a value from the dictionary using the key**
>     `Value = dict(Key)`
> <sub><sup>e.g.</sup></sub> `appleCount = dict("Apples")`

---

### Remove

> **Remove item**
>     `dict.Remove Key`
> <sub><sup>e.g.</sup></sub> `dict.Remove "Apples"`
>
> **Remove all items**
>     `dict.RemoveAll`

---

### Enumerate

> **Loop through all items (`For..Each` loop)**
>     `Dim key As Variant`
>     `For Each key In dict.Keys`
>      `Debug.Print key, dict(key)`
>     `Next key`
>
> **Loop through all items (`For..Next` loop - *early binding only*)**
>     `Dim i As Long`
>     `For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1`
>      `Debug.Print dict.Keys(i),`
>      `dict.Items(i)`
>     `Next i`

---

### Case Sensitivity

> **Make key case sensitive (the dictionary must be empty).**
> `dict.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare`
>
> **Make key non case sensitive (the dictionary must be empty).**
> `dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare`

<sub>(More info at the [**source**](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-articles/): *Paul Kelly Excel Macro Mastery*)</sub>

Comment: Is `dict(key)` just shorthand for `dict.Item(key)`?