# vba initializing a dictionary early and late binding

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, initialization

The following code works in VBA

```
 Dim dict_var As Dictionary
 Set dict_var = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Reading multiple Q&A in stack I come many times across solutions where the code starts by:

```
 Dim aDictionary As Dictionary
Set aDictionary = New Dictionary
```

This late version gives me an error:

Invalid use of New keyword

why? where is the trick here?
Why using one or another method?

thks

> EDIT:
>   There are many questions relating to this issue in stack, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343261/vba-dictionary-references) was suggested.
>   Nevertheless such question relates to a much specific problem of dictionaries of dictionaries.
>   And it does not explain neither what are the implications of early and non-early binding.
>   It would be nice to know in which particular case the following works.

```
Dim aDictionary As Dictionary
```

Or in other words, when it is really necessary:

```
Dim aDictionary As scripting.Dictionary
```

EDIT2:
those are my libraries:
[image]

Comment: Use `Scripting.Dictionary` and not just `Dictionary`. I supect you have a reference set to the Word object library (and possibly *not* to the Scripting runtime, which you need for early binding like that).

Comment: Check using the Object browser ([F2]), that you don't have multiple Dictionary definition

Comment: what is multiple dictionary definition? the same name for several dics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, **both** of your code sets are early bound. To late bind, you would declare the variable as an `Object`.

Second, as to the specific error, I would suspect that you have references set to two libraries that have a `Dictionary` class in them - for example Word and the Scripting Runtime - and that the one that is higher in the references list is a single instance object so you can't use `New` with it.

Comment: can you please have a look at the new added pic in the question?

Comment: @Berlines That ties in with what I said. Your reference to Word is above the `Scripting.Runtime` reference. Given that scenario, you should get a Type Mismatch error with your first code.

Comment: thanks a lot. I did not even know that I had to take care what and in which order that is clicked there. I will unclick the word one and ready-

Comment: @Berlines You don't have to remove references - just fully qualify your object types.