# Create dictionary in function and use it in a sub

Tags: vba, function, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary in a function that is used in a sub, but I get the error

> "User defined type not defined".

I don't know if it's very obvious but I can't see what is the problem.

I've simplified the code to make a simple code:

```
Public Function create_dic(ByVal var As String) As Dictionary

   my_dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

   If var = "test" Then
       my_dic.Add Key:="var 1", Item:=1
   Else
       my_dic.Add Key:="var 2", Item:=2
   End If

   Set create_dic = my_dic
            
End Function
    

Sub prueba()
    Set respuesta = create_dic("test")
End Sub
```

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I didn't know about that. All my problems are solved now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set a reference to the *"Microsoft Scripting Runtime"*? `Dictionary` is not part of standard VBA and needs the library. See [VBA Dictionary References](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51344802/3219613).

Also when you use `my_dic.CompareMode` it does not exist yet. Make sure you use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables properly. Also you need to create a new dictionary object first before you can use it.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function create_dic(ByVal var As String) As Dictionary
   Dim my_dic As Dictionary  ' declare variable type
   Set my_dic = New Dictionary  ' create a new dictionary object

   my_dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

   If var = "test" Then
       my_dic.Add Key:="var 1", Item:=1
   Else
       my_dic.Add Key:="var 2", Item:=2
   End If

   Set create_dic = my_dic
            
End Function
    

Public Sub prueba()
    Dim respuesta As Dictionary  ' declare variable type
    Set respuesta = create_dic("test")
End Sub
```

For more about dictionaries this is a good reference: [Excel VBA Dictionary – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/).