# Find name of array

Tags: arrays, vba

I have this code:

```vb
Array1 = Array("apple", "pear")
Array2 = Array("Dog", "Cat")

All_Arrays = Array(Array1, Array2) 
For each item in All_Arrays
    Debug.print item
Next item
```

I want to change it to print the variable **names** `Array1` and `Array2`. Is this possible?

Comment: You will need to put the name as one item in each array, then you can access it.

Comment: There are no *reflection* capabilities in VBA, an `Array` is not an object and it does not have a name, or any other properties or methods. If you need identifier names as data, include identifier names in your data.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: At first glance, related to the *no properties* part, one might think: *Wait a minute, what about the array limits (`LBound` and `UBound`)?* Then, after a re-think, you would understand that they are not properties since you can't e.g. do `arr.LBound` but rather do `LBound(arr)`. How would you describe the relationship between an array and the `LBound` and `UBound` functions (since they are somewhat related to the `Count` property of the other data structures (collection, dictionary, and the less-used array list and sorted list))?

Comment: `LBound` and `UBound` are actually [special-form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/7df907cb-ab6c-40d3-aa81-272742ce00c3) syntax, which makes them closer to *operators* than *functions*! Arrays in VBA are internally [SAFEARRAY structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/introducing-the-safearray-data-structure), which indeed includes a pointer to another struct that describes the array's boundaries - but these are *very* far removed from properties like `ArrayList.Count`!

Comment: @VBasic2008 (forgot to ping in previous reply!) in other words `LBound` and `UBound` are language-level tooling to access particular specific values in a particular specific data structure. `ArrayList` and `SortedList` are entirely different beasts, being COM-visible .NET objects; their `Count` *property* is inherited from a common interface (`ICollection`), a mechanism that is different than what `Collection.Count` and `Dictionary.Count` do (`VBA.Collection` and `Scripting.Dictionary` do not share a common interface).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a `Dictionary`, keyed with the identifier names:

```vb
Dim Array1 As Variant
Array1 = Array("apple", "pear")

Dim Array2 As Variant
Array2 = Array("Dog", "Cat")

With New Scripting.Dictionary

    .Add "Array1", Array1
    .Add "Array2", Array2

    Dim names As Variant
    names = .Keys

    Dim outer As Long
    For outer = LBound(names) To UBound(names)

        Dim k As String
        k = names(outer)

        Debug.Print k & ":"

        Dim inner As Long
        For inner = LBound(.Item(k)) To UBound(.Item(k))
            Debug.Print vbTab & .Item(k)(inner)
        Next
    Next

End With
```

Output:

```
Array1:
    apple
    pear
Array2:
    Dog
    Cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, use nested arrays all the time...

```
For iArr = 0 to ubound(All_Arrays)
    subArr = All_Arrays(iArr)   '0 will be Array1, 1 will be Array2
    'Then do whatever you want with subArr
next iArr
```

edit1: Oh, maybe you want the actual variable name? "Array_1" and "Array_2" as strings? That is not possible (to my knowledge) without explicitly handing back a string of the name. i.e.

```
All_Arrays_Names = Array("Array1", "Array2")
```

edit2: Maybe it is possible, but its certainly not trivial: [Print a variable's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173082/print-a-variables-name)

Comment: But this will not print `Array1` and `Array2` it will only print the items inside those arrays.  I believe the OP wants to print the variable name of the array, which is not possible.

Comment: Realised that after posting it and did an edit. Yep, as you say - not possible. (At least as far as I know)

Answer (score 0):

**Very basic alternative using a jagged array**

An array is no object disposing of something like a `.Name` property, but you might build an array of arrays, aka as *jagged array* defining your own names therein.

The idea is to use a **jagged array**'s first element(row) as *container* for the array *names*, whereas only the succeeding elements contain the relevant arrays. Instead of @MathieuGuindon 's valid dictionary approach, the names can be read in directly from the jagged array (e.g. via a help function `Header()` here).

Note that the array names in this example are referred to as ordinal numbers (1-based).

*The following code intends to demonstrate an alternative approach giving a **basic** starting idea and could be changed individually covering more sophisticated needs. This might include error handling, accepting other array bases and functions as well as developping additional class methods or properties.*

```
Sub testJagged()
    Dim jagged: ReDim jagged(2)
    jagged(0) = Array("Array1", "Array2")
    jagged(1) = Array("Apple", "Pear")
    jagged(2) = Array("Dog", "Cat")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(jagged) + 1 To UBound(jagged)
        Debug.Print header(jagged, i) & ":"
        Debug.Print vbTab & Join(jagged(i), vbNewLine & vbTab)
    Next
    
    'how to refer to array names and selected elements
    Dim NamedElem
    For Each NamedElem In jagged(0)
        Debug.Print "all Elems of " & NamedElem & ": " & _
            Join(getNamedArray(jagged, NamedElem), ",")
        Debug.Print "1st Elem  of " & NamedElem & ": " & _
            getNamedArray(jagged, NamedElem)(0)
    Next


End Sub
```

**Help function `Header()`**

```
Function header(arr, ByVal OrdinalHeaderNum As Long)
'Note: assumes zero-based headers in jagged array
    header = arr(LBound(arr))(OrdinalHeaderNum - 1)
End Function
```

**Help function `getNamedArray()`**

```
Function getNamedArray(arr, ByVal ArrName As String)
    Dim num As Variant
    num = Application.Match(ArrName, arr(LBound(arr)), 0)
    If IsNumeric(num) Then getNamedArray = arr(num)
End Function
```

**Output in VB Editor's immediate window:**

```
Array1:
    Apple
    Pear
Array2:
    Dog
    Cat

all Elems of Array1: Apple Pear
1st Elem  of Array1: Apple
all Elems of Array2: Dog Cat
1st Elem  of Array2: Dog
```