# VBA get instance name inside of class

Tags: vba

```
Sub Main()
    Dim test As New Class1
End sub
```

**Class1:**

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    msgbox(Name_of_Class_Instance)   
End Sub
```

I want the msgbox to show "Test"

Can that be done in VBA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use ObjPtr(Me) to return the Name of a Custom Class Instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487567/use-objptrme-to-return-the-name-of-a-custom-class-instance)

Comment: You can't, there is no real reflection in VBA and locals are not published in any COM interfaces you can examine.  Hard to see a use case for wanting to do this but you could simply assign "test" to a property.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are trying to get the **class instance name** which is declared in **module.**

First of all you need to do is create a class like below.

```
Public classname As String

'Below method is going to get the value from module.

Public Sub Class_Initialize()
MsgBox classname
End Sub
```

Second, create a module like below.

```
Sub getname()

Dim test As Class1
Set test = New Class1

'Here we are passing the class name as 'test' and executing the 'Class_Initialize' method

With test
.classname = "test"
.Class_Initialize
End With

End Sub
```

Now you will get the instance name of the class.

Comment: `Class_Initialize()` is the object's constructor and it's private - it shouldn't be called outside the class.

Comment: Class_Initialize() is a method and am passing the string value in module. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: `Class_Initialize()` is called automatically when you create an instance of the class using the `new` keyword e.g. `Set test = New Class1`.

Comment: @KostasK. So is there anyway to pass the arguments when the instance has been created? Like Set test = New Class1(name="test")

Comment: In VBA no, you can't. Usually you overcome this by defining another sub to pass your parameters e.g. `test.Init Name:="Some Value"`